Join/fill in data based on both row and column values
I am trying to make a new data frame that will overlay (so wherever there is a non-NA value in a cell, there is a corresponding value in the new data frame) with my original, which looks something like this:
    SiteData <- data.frame(
      Site = c("Apple", "Apple", "Pear"),
      ID   =  c(1:3),
      1/1/2020  = c(NA,1,1),
      1/8/2020  = c(1,1,1),
      1/15/2020 = c(1,0,NA),
      1/22/2020 = c(0,NA,NA)
    )
    
SiteData

    Site ID 1/1/2020 1/8/2020 1/15/2020 1/22/2020
    Apple 1   NA        1         1        0
    Apple 2    1        1         0        NA
    Pear  3    1        1         NA       NA

Based on the site, I would like to make it so that all 1s and 0s in the new data frames will be replaced with the appropriate weather data for that time.
Weather data example:
    WeatherData <- data.frame(
              Site = c("Apple", "Pear"),
              1/1/2020  = c(5,8),
              1/8/2020  = c(7,10),
              1/15/2020 = c(2,3),
              1/22/2020 = c(1,2)
            )  

WeatherData
  
    Site 1/1/2020 1/8/2020 1/15/2020 1/22/2020
    Apple   5       7          2        1
    Pear    8       10         3        2

Ultimately the goal would be for the end result to look like this:
Site ID 1/1/2020 1/8/2020 1/15/2020 1/22/2020
Apple 1   NA        7         2        1
Apple 2    5        7         2        NA
Pear  3    8       10         NA       NA

How do I accomplish this and join by both row value and column name?

1/1/2020  = c(NA,1,1), is not proper syntax for two reasons: you haven't put quotes around 1/1/2020 to specify it's a name, and even then, names that start with numbers are not syntactic in R. If you named them like "1/1/2020", R will rename them like X1.1.2020. Can you please edit the code so it runs?

The general approach I would take would be to reshape both tables long. Then it's a simple join, and you could reshape wide again if that is needed.

I would suggest reshaping both tables long. Then it's a join to link them based on Site and name (in this case based on the date, stored as column name originally). The new data should use the second table's values (value.y) if value.x isn't NA. Then we can reshape wider again.
library(tidyverse)
left_join(     
  SiteData |> pivot_longer(-(Site:ID)),
  WeatherData |> pivot_longer(-Site), join_by(Site, name)) |>
  mutate(new = if_else(!is.na(value.x), value.y, NA)) |>
  select(-value.x, -value.y) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = new)

Result
  Site     ID X1.1.2020 X1.8.2020 X1.15.2020 X1.22.2020
  <chr> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Apple     1        NA         7          2          1
2 Apple     2         5         7          2         NA
3 Pear      3         8        10         NA         NA


SiteData <- data.frame(
  Site = c("Apple", "Apple", "Pear"),
  ID   =  c(1:3),
  X1.1.2020  = c(NA,1,1),
  X1.8.2020  = c(1,1,1),
  X1.15.2020 = c(1,0,NA),
  X1.22.2020 = c(0,NA,NA)
)

WeatherData <- data.frame(
  Site = c("Apple", "Pear"),
  X1.1.2020  = c(5,8),
  X1.8.2020  = c(7,10),
  X1.15.2020 = c(2,3),
  X1.22.2020 = c(1,2)
)  


You may be able to use rows_update() and then restore the original NA values:
library(dplyr)

SiteData |> 
  rows_update(WeatherData, by = "Site") |> 
  replace(is.na(SiteData), NA)

   Site ID X1.1.2020 X1.8.2020 X1.15.2020 X1.22.2020
1 Apple  1        NA         7          2          1
2 Apple  2         5         7          2         NA
3  Pear  3         8        10         NA         NA


Nice, that's very neat.
